# code in framework 1.1 giving comptibility issues

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, compatibility

I have project which is currently working and was developed long time back on dot net famework 1.1. Now here we are using visual studio 2010 and when i make any modifications to the project and upload it, I get error regarding compatibility. Can I convert this project so that I can make changes and it doesn't give me compatibility problem on uploading on server? If yes, can u please tell me how? Or will I have to write the whole project again?

i53.tinypic.com/9iwk6w.jpg

tinypic.com?ref=9iwk6w

Comment: Please post the exact, full error message.

Comment: It gives you the error "when you upload it"?  How are you uploading it?  Or does it give the error at some other event, such as when try to run it on the server?  Is this a web app, console app, etc.?

Comment: @john: It is not allowing to upload pic, So I have posted url.. please see that.

Comment: @david: After uploading when I run it, then it gives error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that the application running on the server can't find the Crystal Reports libraries.  Those will need to be deployed to or installed on the server.

The Crystal Reports was dropping with Visual Studio 2010.  If you upgraded your workstations to 2010 then the runtime libraries are likely still there from a previous version (note that multiple versions of VS run concurrently on the same machine just fine).  So the code will continue to build and run fine locally because the Crystal Reports libraries are globally available on the workstations.

What is your build/deploy process?  It seems that it was including the Crystal Reports runtime libraries previously but isn't now.  When building in Visual Studio 2010, if the code has a dependency on the Crystal Reports libraries, where are the references pointing?  You'll probably want to encapsulate those references into the build rather than rely on pulling them from the GAC or wherever you're getting them.  Maybe include them in a lib folder with other 3rd party DLLs, etc.

Comment: Hmmm CR support was recently added for VS2010 as a separate download: http://www.businessobjects.com/jump/xi/crvs2010/default.asp

Comment: @gmagana and @David
 Thanks every one :) now that should certainly help

Answer (score 1):

Take a closer look at the error message.  You need to install the Crystal Reports runtime on your web server so you can generate the report.  It really has nothing to do with .NET 1.1.

Comment: Then what about version 3.5 and 10.5 ?

Comment: That is telling you that it is not finding Crystal Reports runtime for CR version 10.5 under .NET 3.5.  In other words, the referenced version of the CR runtime is missing.  If it worked before, it was because the server has the older runtime installed, now it wants to find the new one.

Comment: How do I install crystal reports now? or what exactly should I do now? sorry.. but I am new in dot net